# Get all records from previous month WITH one result per user AND maximum column per user

Tags: mysql, pdo

Basically, what I'm trying to do is get the top x reputation users from the last month in (currently all forums). I apologise if this has already been asked, but I have searched and haven't found anything.

The table structure:

*Note: I'm only showing relevant columns here, there are more.*

reputation

```
id | given_by | post_id | vote | time_given

1  | 2        | 1       |  1   | 1390763007
2  | 6        | 2       |  -1  | 1390763013
3  | 7        | 2       |  -1  | 1390763013
```

(and there is an entry for every vote in the table below)

posts

```
 id | poster_id  | reputation | posted

1   | 4          |  1         | 1390763013
2   | 3          |  -2        | 1390763013
3   | 8          |  4         | 1390763013
4   | 4          |  5         | 1390763013
```

There is a topics table and forums table, which I will eventually introduce too. But really I'd like to get it working simply first.

```
$date = getdate(time());
$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date['mon'], 1, $date['year']);

//$sql = "SELECT u.username, u.id, u.group_id, p.reputation FROM reputation AS r LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON r.post_id = p.id LEFT JOIN users AS u ON p.poster_id = u.id WHERE p.reputation > '0' AND p.posted <= :time ORDER BY p.posted DESC";
$sql1 = "SELECT p.id FROM posts AS p WHERE p.id = :id";
$ps1 = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$sql = "SELECT r.post_id FROM reputation AS r WHERE r.time_given >= :time ORDER BY r.time_given DESC";
$ps = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$ps->execute(array(':time'=>$time));
$ps->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($ps as $reputation)
{
    print_r($reputation);
    $ps1->execute(array(':id'=>$reputation['post_id']));
}
```

The first query works, but it will bring up the poster IDs multiple times, if for example they have got more than one bit of reputation in the past month. Somehow, I need a function to sum the function variable, which will add up all of the reputation by poster x in the posts table, with no rows of the same poster again, showing only positive reputation and ordering it by the reputation grouped descending - so the example in the table above should appear like this from MySQL:

```
poster_id | reputation

 4        | 6
 8        | 4
```

It's the grouping part I'm struggling with, I could do this through PHP but I'd much rather do it through MySQL and only have to loop through the results.

I'd rather have this in one query, but two at the most.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question.  You say you want an average, but your table at the bottom shows sums.  Which are you looking for?  do you want a sum of reputation by poster_id?

Comment: Yeah - sorry, a sum of the reputation. I was thinking of GROUP BY and average functions when I said that.

Comment: ok, see answer below

Comment: posts have reputation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do calculations on fields within a table.  You just need to group by the other items in the select, like so:

```
SELECT poster_id, sum(reputation) as reputation
FROM posts
group by poster_id
```

Comment: you had all the data you needed on one table :) (there are instances where you may need the join, but not this one)